# Why do suborbital planes feature H-tail and/or large wingtips?

Tags: supersonic, high-altitude

Spaceplanes that are suborbital are mostly supersonic and feature H-tail or rather large wingtips. This looks to be similar to a H-tail configuration but I'm unsure abut how it works, which is why I say large wing tips. They focus on a delta wing and elevon for the pitch and roll and yaw seems to be controlled using this.
For example look at the following spaceplanes. [image: vss unity][image: dream chaser NASA][image: (Cancelled) XCOR Lynx]

References:
1. https://www.virgingalactic.com/articles/VSS-Unity-First-Powered-Flight/
2. https://www.sncorp.com/what-we-do/dream-chaser-space-vehicle/
3. https://www.flyfighterjet.com/xcor-lynx-space-flight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most spaceplanes are aerodynamically just hypersonic airplanes. The tailless delta wing with directional stabilising fins on the tips is an optimal solution, especially if you do not want a fin on the fuselage. Directional stability can be elusive and highly non-linear, so types designed before the days of high-speed digital control systems often resorted to extra-large surfaces.

During re-entry a spaceplane cannot nosedive or it would overheat and melt or tear itself to bits. It has to kind of pancake down on its underside, keeping just enough forward speed to maintain aerodynamic control (An orbital craft needs hi-tech heat insulation even for this but for suborbital craft it is unlikely to be needed). The safe angle for this manoeuvre is really quite small with little room for error, just a few degrees either way. It was an acceptable risk for the Space Shuttle but may not be for commercial passenger flights.

SpaceShipOne and Two are a unique solution to the problem of safe re-entry. The tail configuration is known as the outboard tail or outboard horizontal stabilizer (OHS). It has been studied from time to time but never really flown (a German research prototype was built in WWII but it is unclear whether it ever flew). It was adopted for the SpaceShip series for the obvious reason that it gets the stabilizer out of the way of the rocket exhaust. It also eased the mechanical solution to their other big aerodynamic innovation, the variable-geometry "weathercock" tail. By swinging the tail up for re-entry, it stabilises the spaceplane as it pancakes back down, hugely increasing the safe zone and making re-entry almost trivially safe.

Passengers returning from actual orbit present a far greater challenge, as yet unsolved.

Answer (score 3):

Dreamchaser isn't intended to be suborbital. Don't know about your 3rd picture, but the Spaceship 1 & 2 were designed by the same person/company, so it's not surprising they use the same design elements.

The designs of Dreamchaser vs Spaceship N address two different problems.  An orbital vehicle has to decelerate from ~17,000 mph, while a suborbital vehicle on a ballistic trajectory (simplistically straight up and straight down) starts from zero speed at its high point, and needs to keep from gaining too much speed.  So if I'm not mistaken, a main function of the H-tail is to allow the entire vehicle to act as a drag device.  That wouldn't be practical for an orbital reentry vehicle due to heating & aerodynamic forces.

Comment: Dream Chaser worries about gaining too much speed too, especially during re-entry.  Both it and Space Ship 2 want to stably slow down from space to atmosphere and glide home.  The third plane is concept only, it's company went out of business.

Comment: In other words, after deorbit burn, Dream Chaser, now suborbital, but with much more potential and kinetic energy, must slow down and glide as well.  So needs heat shield, Space Ship 2, not as much.

Comment: @Robert DiGiovanni:  As I said, suborbital flights start from essentially zero speed at the top of their arc, and want to keep from gaining speed (think parachute).  Any orbital reentry vehicle starts from orbital speed (otherwise it wouldn't be in orbit, of course) and slows down.  The problem there is to manage the slowing in a controlled way.

Comment: Here's where it gets good. An object in orbit starts with 0 vertical speed as well. It's all potential energy.  It does have horizontal speed, and so does sub-orb (think Redstone). The task of returning to around 200 knot glide through the air is the same, why separate them?  There for Dream Chaser is qualified for sub-orb flight.  Imagine how much smaller the Space Shuttle's fuel tanks would be if it were sub orb as well.

Comment: When Spaceship 2 feathers in vacuum, it will accelerate quite a bit before entering denser atmosphere.  Not enough for significant heating, so I agree the strategy is more "parachute".  Both want to be stable, hence the heartfelt efforts at weight low, drag high.

Comment: Going straight down requires G forces to pull out.  I would hang on to some horizontal V and try to stretch my vertical descent over time.  Compare Mercury Gs to Space Shuttle!

Comment: @Robert DiGiovanni: First, speed is not a vector quantity.  Second, per Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceShipOne Spaceship 1's maximum speed is about 2000 mph (900 m/s) vs the 17K mph (7800 m/s) of orbital velocity.  So obviously the energy you need to dissipate in returning from orbit is much greater, as are the structural forces & heating.  WRT stretching the slowing over time, of course.  I'm just looking at the worst case, which is going straight down until you need to pull out.

Comment: We humans measure altitude in feet and distance in miles.  An object falling at 1200 mph (20 miles per minute) would impact the earth in 60 seconds from 100,000 feet.  Good thought conceptually, but straight down is not an option from space.  Certainly wishing Spaceship 2 the best though, they have worked very hard to get it flying!

Comment: @ Robert DiGiovanni: Humans - at least some of us - may use feet and miles.  Wikipedia uses meters &c, and I'm too lazy to do the conversion.  WRT falling straight down, SS1 would start from an altitude of 62 miles (!327K ft) or greater (that being the definition of "space" for the X-prize), and zero vertical speed. so it would take rather more than 60 seconds to impact the Earth, even if not slowed by air friction.  Which slowing - coming full circle - is the purpose of the H-tail arrangement.

Comment: Depends what you like, the Lancaster has an H tail, the B 29 straight vertical.  Not too happy with SS2 Gs.  Read how Apollo reduced theirs by lifting (gliding) the capsule instead of ballistic trajectory.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The massive winglets on a very slender delta wing are needed for directional stability and for a successful landing as a glider. While a central fin also would provide directional stability, it would produce higher sideslip-induced rolling due to its high location on the fuselage. Next, the rear fuselage is mainly a shell around the rocket motor and would need to be heavier to tolerate the loads from a massive tail. By shifting the vertical tails to the wingtip, they become more effective from their more rearward location.

But more important for the wingtip location of the fins is the L/D which would be too low without them for flaring during landing, especially in case of the Dreamchaser and the European Hermes re-entry vehicle project. Without the improvement in L/D, both would lose too much kinetic energy during the flare to cut down their sink speed before they stall.

Answer (score 2):

At extreme speed, the more symmetry you have, the better your chances are of staying straight.  This is especially of concern at very high altitudes, where
aerodynamic forces (indicated airspeed) are small.
X15 is good example of this.  Also, H type tail helps
keep control surfaces away from the rocket nozzle.

Shuttle type vehicles also emphasize roll and pitch stability in re-entry.  Very interesting to note the humble capsule has 360 degrees of roll stability (there for also pitch). The Soviets liked the ball, with the weight set a little low, for the same reason.

Space ship 2 has the (shuttle cock) feathered configuration.  Dream Chaser (and the Air Force)
has strong dihedral. These just want to come in upright and land safely.